# Flutter problem : How to show message when name not contains?

Tags: angular, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### How to show message when my data is not contains after search?

How to show message when my data is not contains after search?
How to show message when my data is not contains after search?
How to show message when my data is not contains after search?
How to show message when my data is not contains after search? How to show message when my data is not contains after search? How to show message when my data is not contains after search? How to show message when my data is not contains after search?
This is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'ListView with Search'),
    );
  }
}

class myclass {
  String word1;
  String word2;

  myclass(this.word1, this.word2);
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  final duplicateItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");
  var items = List<String>();

  List<myclass> words = [
    myclass("Start", "دەستپێدکت"),
    myclass("Go", "دچت"),
    myclass("Drive", "دهاژوت"),
    myclass("Sleep", "دنڤت"),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: words.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (editingController.text.isEmpty) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title:
                            Text('${words[index].word1} ${words[index].word2}'),
                      );
                    } else if (words[index]
                            .word1
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(editingController.text) ||
                        words[index]
                            .word2
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(editingController.text)) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title:
                            Text('${words[index].word1} ${words[index].word2}'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use if condition and show your data in condition like this words[index].isEmpty()
When you have empty data you can print or show specific data

Comment: @DipakRamoliya No Its not working

Answer (score 0):

change the last line from:

```
} else {
    return Container();
  }
```

to this:

```
} else {
    return index == 0 ? Text('No Such a things') : Container();
  }
```